# How to poll a specific HTTP POST

Tags: ajax, polling

OK, so I am submitting an http POST like normal to a specific URL with parameters

```
var request = OpenLayers.Request.POST({
url: "http://test/services",
data: params
```

});

The XML I get back from the server contains information on the % complete the (WPS) process is. Initially, when I send the POST, I get 0%, of course. I want to figure out how to retrieve the exact same XML so I can poll and create a progress bar. If I replicate the POST, it creates a brand new process. SO I won't get back that same process.

So I just can't figure out how exactly to continue polling to get the XML how I need. Maybe I need to configure a GET somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about working with IDs? The Post return the ID of the process and with additional GETs with this ID as parameter return the current progress.